# Upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 fails

Tags: upgrade

I previously upgraded another system and had a few issues, but a simple `sudo apt dist-upgrade` continued the upgrade and solved that issue.

An upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 for a second system fails with the error message:

```
systemd-machine-id-setup: /lib/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found (required by /lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-245.so)
```

Specifically, I am upgrading Kubuntu and used the directions from the following site:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades/Kubuntu

From `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518699/error-while-starting-open-ssh-usr-sbin-sshd-lib-libcrypt-so-1-version-xcr`, I found that `libcrypt.so.1` was a soft link `/lib/libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.30.so`.  I removed the soft link so that another libcrypt was found, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0`, which seemed more appropriate.

A `sudo apt dist-upgrade` pushed the upgrade farther down the road.  However, it failed again with:

```
/usr/bin/perl: /lib/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found (required by /usr/bin/perl)
```

Obviously, something in the install recreated the link: `/lib/libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.30.so`

I'm sure libcrypt-2.30.so is great and all, but it's fubar'ing the upgrade process with this soft link.  WTF?!?  Here is where the failure occurs during this iteration of the upgrade:

```
...
Processing triggers for cups (2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1) ...
Updating PPD files for hpcups ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
perl: /lib/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found (required by perl)
...
```

I'm betting the `libc-bin` somehow reinstated the link.

Using `dpkg -S /lib/libcrypt-2.30.so` shows that `libc6-udeb` installs the `/lib/libcrypt-2.30.so` file.   The `libc6-udeb` package didn't have any dependency relationships, so `sudo apt remove libc6-udeb`.  This removed the offending files, link, and seems to continue the upgrade. A `sudo apt dist-upgrade` seems to indicate the upgrade was completed.  A `sudo apt autoremove` was used to complete the process.

So, what's up with that?  I have installed a variation of different repositories, packages, and such, but I've rarely had an upgrade process fail so badly without (usually) a simple `dpkg --configure -a` or similar (maybe a bit more complicated) fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sudo apt remove libc6-udeb` seems to fix the issue as shown in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this kind of an issue while upgrading a VM from Debian 10 to 11 (buster to bullseye), so I'll note it here in case anyone else ever bumps into it. The symptoms are pretty scary as most of the system tools stop being able to start and all you have is the upgrade session's shell which still didn't die.

The problem was that the /lib/libcrypt.so.1 symlink was pointing to the older file /lib/libcrypt-2.11.3.so which had a timestamp from 2014, not to the newer file provided by the current libcrypt1 package, /lib/$arch-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0 which had a timestamp from 2021.

There's information in the Debian bug tracking system about some ordering issues that were since fixed, but in my case I ran out of disk space mid way through the dist-upgrade, which may have screwed up the ordering in a similar way.

The fix was just to run ln -sf in the working shell to switch it over manually.

Also, the old library file, that dpkg -S no longer recognized, had to be manually moved out of the library paths so that the links stayed correct.