# Problems upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04 due to problems with systemd

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies, systemd

This is similar to [Upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254845/upgrade-from-19-10-to-20-04-fails).  However, in my case, `apt remove libc6-udeb`  did not clear the issue.  Neither did

```
root@jeffs-desktop:~# apt --fix-broken install systemd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
systemd is already the newest version (245.4-4ubuntu3.2).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.30.0-7) but 5.28.1-6build1 is to be installed
                                Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libcrypt-openssl-random-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.30.0-7) but 5.28.1-6build1 is to be installed
                                Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.30.0-7) but 5.28.1-6build1 is to be installed
                             Depends: perlapi-5.30.0
 python3-systemd : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.7.5-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@jeffs-desktop:~# more /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
root@jeffs-desktop:~#
```

It seems that no matter what else I try, I always seem to get the same result:

```
Setting up systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
systemd-machine-id-setup: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found (required by /lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-245.so)
systemd-machine-id-setup: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_4.4' not found (required by /lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-245.so)
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@jeffs-desktop:~#
```

am I to the point where I just say "to hell with it" and install 20.04 from USB?

Comment: A quick look shows your paste is providing an *eoan* package https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=perl  so more details on where you are would be nice. Did the *release-upgrade* complete?  what command did you use? have you rebooted?  if you `sudo apt update` do you get any errors? and everything looks good for your release (be it *eoan* or *focal*??) and then if no errors and all expected lines are there, I'd next `sudo apt full-upgrade` until you have no issues, then finally reboot. Read & follow messages

Answer (score 0):

- you can install `apt install libcrypt-dev` which will add `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so`
- you can do `apt install -f` to try to resolve the issue
- you can also try to (force) reinstall via `apt install --reinstall systemd` which should pull the dependencies

Comment: Didn't work.  I can send you the gory details if you like.  I think the problem is that I can't install libcrypt-dev because systemd is broken, but systemd requires a specific version of libcrypt.  I'm in this circular dependency hell.

Comment: You can download the specific `.deb` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libcrypt-dev/download) for `libcrypt-dev`, and then install it via `dpkg -i libcrypt-dev.deb` which will install the package, and work from there?